# React - Fabric Js getActiveObject not working

Tags: html, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs, react-canvas

I'm new to React with Fabric Js. I just tried to set current active image. My problem is after selecting setting `getActiveObject()` the canvas image is gone to white color. I tried with some methods, but I can't find the solution.

Demo Link: https://o8n8h.csb.app/
Codesandbix Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-platform-o8n8h?file=/src/App.js

Here is my sample code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { fabric } from "fabric";
export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.clg();
  }
  clg = () => {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("a");
    canvas.add(
      new fabric.Rect({
        left: 50,
        top: 50,
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        fill: "red"
      })
    );
    canvas.add(
      new fabric.Rect({
        left: 70,
        top: 70,
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        fill: "green"
      })
    );
    canvas.add(
      new fabric.Rect({
        left: 90,
        top: 90,
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        fill: "blue"
      })
    );
    canvas.renderAll();
  };
  bringToFront = () => {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("a");
    var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    activeObj &&
      canvas
        .bringToFront(activeObj)
        .discardActiveObject(activeObj)
        .renderAll();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas id="a" width="200" height="200" />
        <button onClick={this.bringToFront}>Bring to front</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have to initiate the fabric object with option `{preserveObjectStacking: true}` so that the stacking of assets are preserved. e.g.,

`clg = () => { var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("a", { preserveObjectStacking:true }); ...`

In the `bringToFront` click handler function you are getting new fabric object instead of using the old fabric object. What you can do is to save the fabric object in state inside `this.clg` function at the end

`this.setState({ canvas })`

and have that canvas/fabric object retrieved in `bringToFront` as

`var {canvas } = this.state`

This should do the trick. Link to updated codesandbox [Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-wood-k0wo2)